# C++ map array key auto increase

Tags: c++, arrays

In php when you want to create array, by using this:

```
$Data[] = "Val1";
$Data[] = "Val1";
$Data[] = "Val1";
```

php set auto key 0, 1, 2 for this array. I want to know what should I do in c++ in map types or other array types to set int keys auto from 0 to unlimited?

In c++ is something like this:

```
map<int, string> Data;

Data[0] = "val1";
Data[1] = "val1";
Data[2] = "val1";
```

I have to set key myself!

**Is there any way to create struct or template and using that with map?**

Comment: Take a look at [`std::array`](http://de.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) and [`std::vector`](http://de.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)

Comment: Why do insist on a map?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

IIUC, you want to use [`vector`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/):

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>

...

using namespace std;

...

vector<string> Data;
Data.push_back("val1");
Data.push_back("val1");
Data.push_back("val1");

// Now you can access the inserted elements via Data[i]
```

---

See a full example to using this container on [this page](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/vector/).

Comment: Can you pls focus on map ?

Comment: @user216085 It doesn't look at all like the container that is relevant to your problem. Maybe you could explain why you want it specifically.

Comment: Use the set instead. Since you are not aware of size.

Comment: This answer is good, because it focuses on the part that the OP doesn't want included. If the keys aren't important, then simply map is the data structure you should be using. As an alternative, @Sumeet suggested std::set, which is also fitting.

Comment: @user216085 It does satisfy your requirements of an auto-incrementing container.

Answer (score 1):

You can use variable:

```
map<int, string> Data;
int counter = 0;
Data[counter++] = "val1";
Data[counter++] = "val1";
Data[counter++] = "val1";
```

Answer (score 1):

if you are using a map then yes what you've done can be done in a loop to auto-generate the integer keys

```
map<int,string> mymap;
int mymax = 100;

for(int key=0;key<=mymax;++key)//creates a map with 101 keys from 0-100
 mymap[key] = "somestring";

//to check do the following
for(int key=0;key<=mymax;++key)
 std::cout<<mymap[key]<<std::endl;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make a helper function template like

```
template <typename T, typename V>
void add_to_map(map<int, T>& Data, const V& val) {
    Data[Data.size()] = val;
}
```

then

```
map<int, string> Data;

add_to_map(Data, "val1");
add_to_map(Data, "val1");
add_to_map(Data, "val1");
```